# Widget removed from tree after pushing route in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've come across some unexpected behaviour when pushing and popping a route that the Flutter docs haven't been able to explain.

Specifically, when pushing a page route (which is then subsequently popped) from within the results of a `SearchDelegate` that is added to the widget tree via the `showSearch()` function, the widget that is used to display the results is removed from the widget tree and enters an unmounted state.

Consequently, the `BuildContext` that belongs to the widget doing the routing is disposed of, and thus any use of `context` in the build method causes an error. I've provided a sample Flutter program below that illustrates this issue (it's a bit lengthy so bear with me):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return TextButton(
                child: Text("Search"),
                onPressed: () {
                  showSearch(context: context, delegate: Search());
                }
              );
            }
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class Search extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) => SearchResults();
  // Irrelevant
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) => null;
  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) => null;
  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) => Text("Suggestions");
}

class SearchResults extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SearchResultsState createState() => SearchResultsState();
}

class SearchResultsState extends State<SearchResults> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text("Push"),
      onPressed: () async {
        await Navigator.push<String>(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute<String>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => RouteA()
          )
        );
        // ============================= ERROR =============================
        print(mounted); // This should print true (spoiler: it prints false)!
        // =================================================================
      }
    );
  }
}

class RouteA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child:
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Pop"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that this is a simplified version of the program in which I originally witnessed this issue. I'm aware that the widget hierarchy I've presented here may seem a bit nonsensical; however, I'm more interested in why this is happening in the first place for this specific configuration.

Any explanations and appropriate workarounds would be greatly appreciated!